# it can not access popup.js file after creating a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Summer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This is an addition extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form name="form">
            <div id="sayi1">Sayı 1 :    <input type = "text" name="deger1"></div> 
            <div id="sayi2">Sayı 2 :    <input type = "text" name="deger2"></div> 
            <div id="sonuc">Sonuç :     <input type = "text" name="cevap"></div>
            <div id="button"><input type="button" value="Hesapla" onclick="hesaplama()" /></div>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function hesaplama()
{
var sayi1 = window.document.form.deger1.value;
var sayi2 = window.document.form.deger2.value;
var toplam = parseFloat(sayi1) + parseFloat(sayi2) ;
window.document.form.cevap.value = toplam; 
}
```

When i load this extension, i can see normally. But when i filled the deger1 and deger2 textbox and clicked the button, function is not working, in the sonuc textbox (result textbox) is null.
How can i fix it? I am new at creating chrome extensions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Abuse of `eval`? Use `parseFloat(say\u01311) + parseFloat(say\u01312)` instead...

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup

Comment: 1. What are you entering into your inputs? 2. Try running each line individually in the console to make sure what you're expecting to happen is actually what's happening. 2.1 I mean making sure the DOM call returns a value, seeing what `eval(say11)` gives you, etc.

Comment: On console "Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got `manifest_version : 2` in your manifest, so please go read about the changes it introduces....
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html
You got in the console `Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy`, because of the onclick event handler in your html (`<input type="button" value="Hesapla" onclick="hesaplama()" />`).  With manifest version 2 this isnt allowed, you need to attach the event listner from your js code and not in the html.
Here's a working version of your code....
**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <form name="form">
            <div id="sayi1">Sayı 1 :    <input type = "text" name="deger1"></div> 
            <div id="sayi2">Sayı 2 :    <input type = "text" name="deger2"></div> 
            <div id="sonuc">Sonuç :     <input type = "text" name="cevap"></div>
            <div id="button"><input type="button" value="Hesapla" /></div>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function hesaplama()
{
var sayı1 = window.document.form.deger1.value;
var sayı2 = window.document.form.deger2.value;
var toplam = (parseFloat(sayı1) + parseFloat(sayı2)) ;
window.document.form.cevap.value = toplam;
}
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('input[value="Hesapla"]').onclick=hesaplama;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome :)  Oh, and you should probably add an `id` to that input and change the querySelector to look for that instead.